# Sampling property for linear regression estimation

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, estimation

Least Squares Estimation for linear regression is that,

$$\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y$$
Also, it is easy to see that,
$$\hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta, (X^{T}X)^{-1}\sigma^2)$$
If we assume that $X$ is fixed, and $y$ is a random variable.

(1) My question is why we should assume the $X$ is fixed?

(2) In my understanding, $X$ and $y$ should have same "type". If I still want to consider the sampling property with regarding both $X$ and $y$ as random variables, it seems that I should consider about the distribution of $\hat{\beta}~|~X$, $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}~|~X]$ and $Var[\hat{\beta}~|~X]$. Does it make sense?

Comment: Linear regression *does* condition on X. For example, see the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, so if we consider about the sampling property for estimation. Actually, we are going to consider about the distribution of $\hat{\beta} | X$, $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta} | X]$ and $ Var[\hat{\beta} | X]$. Am I right?

Comment: Maybe you should update your question to say "if it does condition on X, then is it correct that we consider the distribution of ..." (the rest following as you just asked); that will make it more likely someone will be able to offer more than the five word answer (*It does condition on X*)